# Obtain Custom Object data from Wrapper Class?

Tags: apex

I have a wrapper class list which include check box values and sobject values like :

```
wrpCarsales:[
    checkbox=false, 
    csb=CarSales_Boot__c:
        {
            Cash_and_Carry_Purchase_Name__c=Independent/Other,
            SKUs_for_Car_Sales__c=Luc Zero Orange,
            No_of_Cases_Bought__c=5,
            Price_per_case_bought__c=6.00,
            Total_Paid__c=30.00,
            User_Boot__c=00526000002Jc6YAAS,
            Date_of_SKU_Purchase__c=2017-02-14 00:00:00
        }
    ]
```

How can I obtain `CarSales_Boot__c`'s object details in order to bind it to a pageblock's table?

This is the apex method I am using:

```
public void removeProducts() {
    Integer selectedCount2 = 0;

    List<Integer> toDelete = new List<Integer>();

    for(integer i = 0; i < wrpList.size(); i++){

        if(wrpList[i].checkbox){
            //first add it to the list to delete:
            toDelete.add(i);
        } else {
            selectedCount2++;       
        }
    }

    // remove it from your list.
    for(Integer x : toDelete){
        wrpList.remove(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Providing your wrapper exposes the SObject using a [property](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) e.g.:

```
public class YourWrapper {
    public CarSales_Boot__c csb {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

you can reference it like this in a Visualforce table:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrpList}" var ="w">
    <apex:column value="{!w.csb.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!w.csb.CreatedDate}"/>
    ...
<apex:pageBlockTable>
```

**PS**

Related to the comment on how to insert the SObjects, you just need to add the references to the new list (no need to modify the `wrpList`):

```
CarSales_Boot__c[] csbs = new CarSales_Boot__c[] {};
for (YourWrapper w : wrpList) {
    csbs.add(w.csb);
}
insert csbs;
```

Comment: @kiran If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Comment: I would tend to prefer to name the property `record` here, personally.

Comment: @Keith C,here I can able to show details in pageblock table ,but inorder to insert sobject details into the DB we have to extract from the wrapper class right,here i am facing the issue.

Comment: actually I am getting wrapper list ,and at the end I have to insert object list into sobject by extracting it from wrapper list...plz suggest better way...wrpList.remove(x); //from this wrplist I have extract sobject details.

Comment: @kiran See the **PS** in the answer.